# how to enforce a date format

Tags: regex, shell, unix

I want to use the date command to output a day of week from user input.

I want to force the input to be of the format MM/DD/YYYY.

For example, at the command line I give

```
./programname MM/DD/YYYY MM/DD/YYYY
```

Snippets from the script itself

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_FORMAT="^[0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" #MM/DD/YYYY
DATE1="$1"
DATE2="$2"
```

... followed by

```
if [ "$DATE1" != "$DATE_FORMAT" ] || [ "$DATE2" != "$DATE_FORMAT" ]; then 
    echo -e "Please follow the valid format MM/DD/YYYY.\n" 1>&2
    exit 1
```

Now the problem is even when I enter correct date formats,

```
./programname 11/22/2014 11/23/2014
```

I still get that error message that I set up, which means that condition for `if` is evaluated true even when I input valid format... any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: You obviously can't use `!=`

Comment: @hek2mgl  if not `!=` what is the correct operator for string vs regex?

Comment: Note that your format is too permissive; the first digit can only be 0 or 1; the third digit can only be 0..3.  I'm not clear whether you want to allow dates back to 1 AD and forward to 9999, but you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE_FORMAT="^[01][0-9][/][0-3][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$" #MM/DD/YYYY
DATE1="$1"
DATE2="$2"

if [[ "$DATE1" =~ $DATE_FORMAT ]] && [[ "$DATE2" =~ $DATE_FORMAT ]]
then echo "Both dates ($DATE1 and $DATE2) are OK"
else echo "Please follow the valid format MM/DD/YYYY ($DATE1 or $DATE2 is wrong)."
fi
```

It uses the `=~` operator for a positive regex match inside Bash's [`[[` test command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b).  The documents don't mention a `!~` for negative matching (though that's what Awk and Perl use).  With the single-bracket `[` test command, there is no regex matching.  Note that the regex expression must *not* be enclosed in double quotes:

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string. Bracket expressions in regular expressions must be treated carefully, since normal quoting characters lose their meanings between brackets. If the pattern is stored in a shell variable, quoting the variable expansion forces the entire pattern to be matched as a string.

The test is also more stringent, rejecting `23/45/2091`, amongst other invalid date strings.

```
$ bash dt19.sh  11/22/2014 11/23/2014
Both dates (11/22/2014 and 11/23/2014) are OK
$ bash dt19.sh  31/22/2014 11/43/2014
Please follow the valid format MM/DD/YYYY (31/22/2014 or 11/43/2014 is wrong).
$
```

Comment: thank you so much. The problem arose from quoting the variable storing the regex. Can you please tell me where you got the documentation regarding quoting?

Comment: It's in the link hidden behind the `[[` in the running text (or, if you prefer, at [the `[[` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b), which is the same link with a bigger amount of text marked as the link).  I've updated the question (needed to fix the shebang anyway) so I altered the link text so it is more visible there, too.

Comment: got it. the link was very helpful :)

Comment: and actually I decided to use more narrow format
^(0[1-9]|1[012])[/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$
that was what i had previously before I discovered the problem with the if condition. now I can use it confidently

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE1="$1"
DATE2="$2"
if echo "$DATE1" | grep -q -E '[0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][/][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
then 
    echo "Do whatever you want here"
    exit 1
else
    echo "Invalid date"
fi
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it's still doing the same thing. I thought in shell scripts you always follow this structure for if statements

`if condition ; then
     dosomething
else
     dosomething1
fi`

Comment: also I'm comparing two strings in the if condition.. so i think -ne is not correct here

Comment: Yeah its true '-ne' and '-eq' are for comparison of values and '!=' is correct.

Comment: The syntax is: if [ expression ]
then
   "Statement(s) to be executed if expression is true"
else
   "Statement(s) to be executed if expression is not true"
fi

Comment: The semicolon followed by `then` is not a part of the trouble.

Comment: `if true; then echo "do something" ; fi` has always been an acceptable form of syntax in Bourne shell derived software.  If you don't believe me, copy/paste the above sample to a command line and execute it ;-) Good luck to all.